# Apache URL Redirect Alternatives

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

One of my clients (before I came along) decided to use htaccess redirects as their form of URL shortening/search engine friendly URLs. They have literally thousands of them.

The new version of the site now has friendly urls but they aren't equivalent to their redirects so they still need them.

My question to you all is: Is there another way than to populate this file with thousands of lines of "Redirects /folder1 /folder2"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot make simple rules to catch all of them as in the @chris henry solution you can use the **RewriteMap** utility of mod_rewrite. You'll be able to write these thousand rules in a text file, then make this text file an hash file, and mode_rewrite will try to match url in this file (if it's an hash file it's quite fast). After that mode_rewwrite can generate a redirect 301 with the `[L,R=301]` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, look at using the Apache config (httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf) to set up site wide folder aliasing. Eg:

```
Alias /folder1 c:/www/folder2
```

Look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how different the URLs being redirected are, one solution might be to come up with an rewrite rule that covers all of them, and maintain the short / long URLs in your application, or even a database.